# How to display the other value of color using the foreach in react

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here's the example code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hook-zwgypv

```
const SIZES = ['_2x', '_3x', '_4x', 'l', 'm', 's', 'xl', 'xs', 'xxs'];

const data = [
  {
    color: 'red',
    _1x: 0,
    _2x: 12,
    _3x: 0,
    _4x: 0,
    xxs: 0,
    xs: 0,
    s: 0,
    m: 0,
    l: 0,
    xl: 0
  },
  {
    color: 'red',
    _1x: 0,
    _2x: 0,
    _3x: 0,
    _4x: 12,
    xxs: 0,
    xs: 0,
    s: 0,
    m: 0,
    l: 0,
    xl: 0
  },
  {
    color: 'pink',
    _1x: 0,
    _2x: 0,
    _3x: 0,
    _4x: 0,
    xxs: 0,
    xs: 0,
    s: 0,
    m: 0,
    l: 14,
    xl: 0
  },
  {
    color: 'red',
    _1x: 0,
    _2x: 0,
    _3x: 0,
    _4x: 0,
    xxs: 0,
    xs: 0,
    s: 0,
    m: 0,
    l: 14,
    xl: 0
  },
  {
    color: 'pink',
    _1x: 0,
    _2x: 0,
    _3x: 0,
    _4x: 0,
    xxs: 0,
    xs: 0,
    s: 14,
    m: 0,
    l: 0,
    xl: 0
  },
  {
    color: 'yellow',
    _1x: 0,
    _2x: 0,
    _3x: 0,
    _4x: 0,
    xxs: 0,
    xs: 0,
    s: 0,
    m: 0,
    l: 0,
    xl: 12
  }
];
const result = Object.values(
      data.reduce((acc, { color, size, ...rest }) => {
        acc[color] = { color };
        Object.keys(rest).forEach(key => {
          acc[color][key] = (acc[color][key] || 0) + rest[key];
        });
        return acc;
      }, {})
    );

    console.log(result);
```

How to display the other value based on the color?
It didn't display the other size of color red and it will sum the same sizes. What I'm trying to do is to display the other sizes of color red.

[image]

example in this photo ^ it will display the size of `_2x` then it will sum the `12` & `9` is equal to `21`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in your reduce you reset `acc[color]` to `{ color }` on each go through so it never has previous values. You only need to set the color the first time when the key doesn't exist yet. You can update your reduce to below:

```js
const result = Object.values(
  data.reduce((acc, { color, size, ...rest }) => {
    if (!acc.hasOwnProperty(color)) {
      acc[color] = {
        color,
        ...rest
      };
      return acc;
    }

    Object.keys(rest).forEach(key => {
      acc[color][key] = (acc[color][key] || 0) + rest[key];
    });

    return acc;
  }, {})
);
```

Updated code example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hook-arh5yz